# “a nice breeze” vs “nice breezes”

Tags: word-choice, singular-vs-plural

> 1. You need to open the windows to get **a nice breeze/nice breezes** in the house.

Can we use both versions? I have heard an American say “a nice breeze”, but that sounded confusing because of the singular “breeze”, and not the plural form “breezes”.

Comment: Here is an example of using the plural  “breezes” *The Grand Canyon, the vast meadows, the evergreens and aspens, **the cool breezes**, the quiet … there’s nothing quite like the Kaibab Plateau and its 44-mile parkway, which begins at Jacob Lake.* (https://www.arizonahighways.com/explore/scenic-drives/north-rim-parkway) and *Our quarters were wooden barracks open on all sides to catch **the cooler breezes**.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both "breeze" and "breezes" can be and are used, as [This Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Let+the+breeze+in%2Clet+the+breezes+in%2Cbreezes+flow%2Cbreezes+flows&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true#) and [this second Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+a+breeze%2Cget+the+breeze%2Cget+breezes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20a%20breeze%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20the%20breeze%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20breezes%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cget%20a%20breeze%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20the%20breeze%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20breezes%3B%2Cc0) shows.

> 1. You need to open the windows to get a nice breeze in the house.
> 2. You need to open the windows to get the nice breeze in the house.
> 3. You need to open the windows to get nice breezes in the house.

Sentence 1 is probably the most common and natural form. Sentence  2 refers to the specific  breeze that is present now, or perhaps to a situation in which there is a constant breeze. Sentence  3 suggests that there is sometimes a breeze and sometimes not, and perhaps they come from different directions, so the plural is used. However the choice between 1 and 3 is really as much a matter of style as of content.

Answer (score 5):

In such a context you don't normally use the plural. Think of ***wind***. Unless you want to make distinctions between the different types of winds, or speak of a particular category of winds (**summer winds, winds of Provence**), or use the idiomatic phrase ***[winds of change](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/winds%20of%20change#:%7E:text=%3A%20forces%20that%20have%20the%20power,change%20have%20begun%20to%20blow.)***, you use the singular to talk about air movement:

> The wind howled about the building.

So I would rather say:

> You need to open the windows and let ***the nice breeze*** in (/into the house). (not breezes)

If you type ***breezes*** in Google the hits that come are either names of shops or bars, or titles of literary works. [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nice%20breeze%2C%20nice%20breezes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnice%20breeze%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnice%20breezes%3B%2Cc0) clearly shows that the plural is not idiomatic.

Edit: As you have understood on your own, "a nice breeze" is not uncountable. I think the plural "breezes" is more natural in meteorological contexts, and also in contexts which relate to wider spaces. Of course, the plural is possible with enclosed spaces, but it is rather particular. The singular is much more common.

Comment: I assume “a nice breeze” is uncountable here, and can be interpreted as “a nice type of breeze”. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Longman lists “breeze” as countable: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/breeze I think confusing what is idiomatic with countability is a rabbit hole we probably don’t want to jump into. There’s a question around here about “the waters” versus “the water” that might be relevant but I can’t find it.

Comment: I don’t think it’s this simple. “The winds drove the ship onto the rocks.” “In Michigan, Gross said, the breezes off the Great Lakes can cause sudden shifts.” There are many many ways to use the plural of breezes or winds correctly/idiomatically.